# Installing Flarum (Laravel framework forum) on my ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, flarum

I was following this guide to install Flarum https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-flarum-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps/
Everything almost went quite smooth, but when it prompted me to make new php-fpm pool for my user, i kind of got lost, and discovered myself in the center of problems.
Guide says, i should issue this command with that text but changing [your user] to my user, so in my case that would of been root

```
 [user]$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/your_user.conf
[your_user]
user = your_user
group = your_user
listen = /var/run/php-fpm-your_user.sock
listen.owner = your_user
listen.group = your_user
listen.mode = 0666
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.max_requests = 200
chdir = /
```

Whenever i tried to restart my php-fpm, i got into problems.

```
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-11-15 19:24:52 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 18263 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/
  Process: 18251 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, st
 Main PID: 18263 (code=exited, status=78)
```

Could i get some help hand here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404655/how-to-run-php-fpm-as-root