# Problem while checking the status of the docker in Jupyter notebook

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I was installing docker in my Jupyter notebook for my project using the commands from this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04).  I installed the docker using the command

```
!sudo apt install docker-ce
```

but after that when I tried to check the status of the docker using the command.

```
!sudo systemctl status docker
```

I got the following error.

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

I saw answers for such questions in [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate) but it is not solving my problem.
For the following command

```
!service --status-all
```

I am getting the following result of which I have no idea. Can someone help me in explaining what I am missing?.

```
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  udev
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

This may be trivial for some of you. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try an image that has Ubuntu with System D already active with this command:

`docker run -d --name systemd-ubuntu --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu`

Then you just need to run:

`docker exec -it systemd-ubuntu /bin/bash`

and there you can just install, start and restart any service you need.