# Can you authorize AWS ECS Fargate with SES on a Laravel App using an IAM policy?

Tags: php, laravel, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, aws-fargate

I'm using AWS ECS for a Laravel app and trying to setup AWS SES. I'm getting the error

```
Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service.
```

I got this to work locally by having Laravel use my default aws profile. However on ECS I would like to authorize by adding the SES access policy to the Task Role. I have already added the allow SES policy to the task role, but I'm still getting the above error. Am I missing something. Is this not possible?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479906/9530790) answer and based on number 3 it should be possible, unless with using Laravel this doesn't work.

##### Update:

I think this issue has something to do with `php-fpm` using `www-data` as the user instead of `root` (recommended due to [security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404788/9530790) ). I'm wondering if when aws adds credentials to the container on startup using IAM, it only adds it for the root user and not other users.

##### Update 2:

The above was not the issue. Even when running `php-fpm` as root, I'm still getting the above error.

##### Update 3:

We came across one issue in where the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI was not being set in the container. This is due to the `CMD` of the Docker file being the PID 1 process and the variable is not available to non-PID 1 processes. See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-access-aws-services/). After fixing that issue, I'm able to call `aws ses` and send an email from the cli inside the container, but I'm still not able to send an email using the http server (from the website).

[image: AWS Variable Note]

Answer (score 0):

After setting the variable inside the container using the method above from 'Update: 3' we then needed to set it as a `fastcgi_param` (see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)) in the nginx conf file so that the http server can have access to the variable. Nginx will need to be started/restarted after defining the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. With various reports and investigation I felt it is fpm which is not loading the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI at runtime and ECS has already injected it into the container.

I create a simple php script using aws-sdk. Executing the script via command-line connects to the respective AWS service without giving any error, but same snippet gave error when requested as http, served by nginx+fpm.

I found [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1971#issuecomment-607143699) comment useful by setting the variable in fpm's conf. But as @shmuels has mentioned it can be set to fastcgi_params and that should work as well.